# Fixed table headers for dynamic column sizes and large number of columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I am creating a table dynamically from Javascript. The structure of the table is as follows. I need to have fixed headers for this dynamically created table.

```
    <table>
    <thead><tr>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th> <!-- the number of columns are based on server response -->
    </tr></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
    <tr><td><td></td></td></tr> <!-- the number of columns correspond to the headers and it varies dynamically -->
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is my javascript code: I am getting the table contents from database. Also I am creating the table dynamically;

```
 require(["jquery","dojox/widget/Standby","dojox/grid/DataGrid","dijit/registry", "dojo/dom-form", "dojo/dom", "dojo/on",  "dojo/request","dojo/parser", "dojo/ready","dojo/domReady!"],
        function($,Standby,DataGrid,registry, domForm, dom, on, request, parser, ready){

    parser.parse();
//  document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "none";
    //document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "hidden";

    var test=registry.byId("basicStandby1");
    var pid=document.getElementById("productNumber").value;

    if((pid != null) || (pid!="")){
        displayGrid(pid);
    }


    function sortByKey(array, key) {
        return array.sort(function(a, b) {
            var x = a[key]; var y = b[key];
            return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ? 1 : 0));
        });
    }
    on(dom.byId("resetButton"), "click", function(){

        location.reload(true);
    });


    function displayGrid(prodNum){

        request("./product/"+prodNum).then(function(list){

            if(list == "fail"){
                registry.byId("basicStandby1").hide();
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML="Product number is not valid";
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }else{

                var table=document.getElementById("productDetail");
                var data=JSON.parse(list);
                var itemDetail=data.product.items;
                delete data.product.items;
                delete data.product.data_longdescription;
                var headerArray=[];
                if(prodNum.trim().charAt(0) =='P'){
                    var table=document.createElement("TABLE");
                    var columnCount=Object.keys(data.product).length;
                    var keys=Object.keys(data.product);
                    var row=table.insertRow(-1);

                    for(var i=0;i<columnCount;i++){
                        var headerCell=document.createElement("TH");
                        var headerName=keys[i]; 
                        var imageURL = data.product[headerName];
                        if((headerName.indexOf("longdescription")>-1)){
                            delete data.product.headerName;
                        }
                        else{
                            if(imageURL.indexOf(".jpg") > -1){
                                data.product[headerName]="<img src='http://prod.tgw.com/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/"+imageURL+"'>";
                            }
                            headerCell.innerHTML=headerName.substring(headerName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                            row.appendChild(headerCell);
                        }
                    }
                    var rowCount=Object.keys(data).length;
                    for(var k=0;k<rowCount;k++){

                        var row=table.insertRow(-1);

                        for(var j=0;j<columnCount;j++){


                            if(!(keys[j].indexOf("longdescription")>-1)){
                                var cell=row.insertCell(-1);
                                var name=keys[j];
                                cell.innerHTML = data.product[name];
                            }
                        }
                    }


                    var div = document.getElementById("productTable");
                    div.appendChild(table);

                }

                var  vv=prodNum.charAt(0);
                if(prodNum.trim().charAt(0) == 'I'){

                    document.getElementById("productTable").innerHTML = "Product Details not available";
                }

                var itemDetailArray=[];
                for(var item in itemDetail){

                    for(var uu in itemDetail[item]){

                        if(!(itemDetailArray.indexOf(uu)>-1)){

                            itemDetailArray.push(uu);
                        }
                    }
                }


                var itemTable = document.createElement('TABLE');
                var itemTableClone = document.createElement('TABLE');
                var itemHead = document.createElement("THEAD");
                var tableBody=document.createElement("TBODY");
                itemTable.appendChild(itemHead);
                itemTable.appendChild(tableBody);


                var row1=itemHead.insertRow(-1);

                itemTable.id='scrollTable';
                itemHead.id='fixedHeader';
                tableBody.id='scrollContent';
                itemTableClone.id='header-fixed';


                var itemArray=[];
                var headerArray=[];
                var arrayCheck=[];
                for (var itemCount in itemDetail){

                    var dataArray=[];
                    var imageArray=[];
                    var itemDetails=[];

                    for (var j in itemDetail[itemCount]){

                        var itemDataDetail=itemDetail[itemCount][j];
                        dataArray.push(j);
                        itemDetails.push({
                            key:j,
                            value:itemDataDetail
                        });


                    }   

                    for (var i in itemDetailArray){

                        if(!(dataArray.indexOf(itemDetailArray[i])>-1)){

                            itemDetails.push({
                                key:itemDetailArray[i],
                                value:null
                            });

                        }
                var myList = sortByKey(itemDetails, "key");     


                    }


                    if(itemCount==0){
                        var headerEDP=document.createElement("TH");
                        headerEDP.innerHTML="EDP Number";
                        row1.appendChild(headerEDP);
                        for (var i in myList){

                            document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "block";
                            document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "visible";
                            var j=myList[i].key;
                            var data=myList[i].value;

                        if(!((j.indexOf("variations.color")>-1)||(j.indexOf("parentid")>-1)||(j.indexOf("partnumber")>-1)||(j.indexOf("image")>-1)||(j.indexOf("ii.mercentSKU")>-1))){

                                if(!(j.indexOf("longdescription")>-1)){


                                    if(j.indexOf("attributes.productid")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="MerchPIN";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);

                                    }else if(j.indexOf("webproductid")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="PID";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }else if(j.indexOf("partnumber")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="EDPNumber";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }else if(j.indexOf("shortdescription")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="Name";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }else if(j.indexOf("tgwesiteproductspricelist")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="Price";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }else if(j.indexOf("msrptgwpricelist")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="SRP";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }else if(j.indexOf("attributes.color")>-1){

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML="ColorCode";
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);


                                    }

                                    else{

                                        var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");
                                        var header_name = itemDetails[i].key;
                                        headerCell1.innerHTML=j.substring(j.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
                                        row1.appendChild(headerCell1);
                                    }
                            }
                            }
                        } 

                    }
                    itemArray=[];
                    headerArray=[];

                    var row2=tableBody.insertRow(-1);
                    var EDPnumber;
                    for (var i in myList){

                        var j=myList[i].key;
                        var data=myList[i].value;


                        if(data!=null){
                            if((j.indexOf("partnumber")>-1)&&(data.trim().charAt(0) =='I')){

                                EDPnumber=data;
                            }
                            if(j.indexOf("image")>-1){

                                if(data.indexOf(".jpg")>-1){

                                    imageArray.push({
                                        key:j,
                                        value:data
                                    });
                                }else{
                                    if(!(j.indexOf("parentid")>-1)){
                                        imageArray.push({
                                            key:j,
                                            value:null
                                        });
                                    }

                                }


                            }
                        }else{
                            if((j.indexOf("image")>-1)){

                                imageArray.push({
                                    key:j,
                                    value:data
                                });
                            }
                        }

                        var j=myList[i].key;
                        var data=myList[i].value;


                        if(!((j.indexOf("variations.color")>-1)||(j.indexOf("parentid")>-1)||(j.indexOf("partnumber")>-1)||(j.indexOf("image")>-1)||(j.indexOf("ii.mercentSKU")>-1))){
                            //if(!((itemArray.indexOf(data) >-1) && (headerArray.indexOf(j.substring(j.lastIndexOf(".") + 1)) >-1))){

                            if(!(j.indexOf("longdescription")>-1)){
                                var cell=row2.insertCell(-1);

                                if(data!=null){
                                    if(data.indexOf(".jpg") > -1){

                                        if(j.indexOf("zoom") > -1){
                                            data="<a href='http://prod.tgw.com/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/"+data+"'>Click to view Zoom Image</a>";
                                            cell.innerHTML=data;

                                        }else{
                                            data="<img src='http://prod.tgw.com/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/"+data+"'>";
                                            cell.innerHTML=data;
                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        cell.innerHTML=data;
                                    }
                                }

                                if(data==null){
                                    cell.innerHTML=data;
                                }

                            }

                        }




                    } 

                    console.log(imageArray);
                    for(var i in imageArray){


                        var imageData=imageArray[i].value;
                        imageKey=imageArray[i].key;
                        if(itemCount==0){
                            var headerCell1=document.createElement("TH");

                            if(imageKey.indexOf("zoom")>-1){
                                headerCell1.innerHTML="Zoom Image";
                            }else if(imageKey.indexOf("fullimage")>-1){
                                headerCell1.innerHTML="Full Image";
                            }else if(imageKey.indexOf("thumbnail")>-1){
                                headerCell1.innerHTML="ThumbNail Image";
                            }else{
                                headerCell1.innerHTML=imageKey;
                            }

                            row1.appendChild(headerCell1);
                        }

                        if((imageArray[i].key).indexOf("zoom") > -1){
                            var cell=row2.insertCell(-1);

                            if(imageData !=null){
                                imageData="<a href='http://prod.tgw.com/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/"+imageData+"'>Click to view Zoom Image</a>";
                            }else{
                                imageData=null;
                            }


                            cell.innerHTML=imageData;

                        }else{
                            var cell=row2.insertCell(-1);

                            if(imageData !=null){
                                imageData="<img src='http://prod.tgw.com/wcsstore/CatalogAssetStore/"+imageData+"'>";
                            }else{
                                imageData=null;
                            }


                            cell.innerHTML=imageData;
                        }


                    }
                    var cell=row2.insertCell(0);
                    cell.innerHTML=EDPnumber;
                }


                var div1 = document.getElementById("tableContainer");
                div1.appendChild(itemTable);
                document.getElementById("tableContainer").className = "tableContainer";
                document.getElementById("scrollTable").className = "fixed_headers";
                document.getElementById("scrollTable").style.width="100%";
                document.getElementById("fixedHeader").className = "fixedHeader";
                document.getElementById("scrollContent").className = "scrollContent";


            }




        });

        //document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "none";
        //document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }






    on(dom.byId("submitButton"), "click", function(){

        registry.byId("basicStandby1").show();
        //document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "none";
        //document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "hidden";
        var table=document.getElementById("productDetail");
        document.getElementById("productTable").innerHTML="";
        document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML="";
        var productNumber=document.getElementById("productNumber").value;
        var domain=document.getElementById("domain").value;
        if(productNumber== ""){
            //registry.byId("basicStandby1").hide();
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").innerHTML="Please enter Product number";
            document.getElementById("productDetail").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("productDetail").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.visibility = "visible";
        }
        else{

            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("errorMessage").style.visibility = "hidden";
            displayGrid(productNumber);

        }
        });

});
```

Below is my css code: This css code I got it from online to have fixed headers but it doesn't seem to work.

```
.fixed_headers {
  width: 750px;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.fixed_headers th {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.fixed_headers th,
.fixed_headers td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(1),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(2),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
}
.fixed_headers td:nth-child(3),
.fixed_headers th:nth-child(3) {
  width: 350px;
}
.fixed_headers thead {
  background-color: #333333;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
.fixed_headers thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.fixed_headers tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.fixed_headers tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
.old_ie_wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 750px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.old_ie_wrapper tbody {
  height: auto;
}
```

Please help me in having a fixed header for this table. I have few other divs and tables displayed separately in the html page. But the above table may contain up to 50 columns of varying width and has to have fixed header on scrolling.

Comment: Can you also provide your javascript code? And any CSS if applicable. What do you mean by fixed?

Comment: I have updated my question with css and js code

Comment: I can't see anything with the code you provided (https://jsfiddle.net/t2tsrdgm/), and it seems you have a lot of unnecessary code that doesn't pertain to your issue. I suggest you take out anything that isn't relevant, and add what we need in order to see your issue. Could you provide a link to an example of what you mean by "fixed" header?

Comment: `document.getElementById("scrollTable").className = "fixed_headers";
document.getElementById("fixedHeader").className = "fixedHeader";`

Is that a typo for the className?